# How to force iPhone to upload to iCloud over mobile data

Tags: iphone, icloud, wifi, data-transfer, data

Using iPhone 10.3.3 with no possibility of WiFi. Is there a way to force the use of mobile data to upload to iCloud?

I understand why the phone will not update using a potentially insecure signal but why won't it allow me to upload my photographs over mobile data?

These issues  are important to people making use of older lower end models. The #Iphone5c is still functional but with very limited scope because of the neglect over maximising use of mobile data and storage issues.

Answer (score 2):

Go to:

Settings -> Photos -> Mobile Data

Then turn on the mobile data switch:

[image: switch]

This will allow upload and download using mobile data.

Turn on *Unlimited Updates* to allow unlimited use of data to upload and download from iCloud when not connected to WiFi.

Beware to go exceed your mobile data plan.